# Displaying arabic letteres with php json_encode

Tags: php, json

I tried the following:

```
header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' );
json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
```

But the output is always:

> Ù…ÙˆØ¹Ø¯ Ù…Ø¹ Ø§Ø­Ù…Ø¯ ÙÙŠ Ø¨ÙŠØ±ÙˆØª

instead there should be arabic title

Comment: Could you provide the full code? (i.e. an example input for $data, and what you're actually outputting on the page, is it the output from json_encode?)

Comment: With your 'exact' code, for `$data['test'] = 'مساء الخير';` I have this output: `{ "test": "مساء الخير" }` (I don't know arabica, original data copied)

Comment: Using Codeigniter,   $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

Comment: the problem is that the page is of type JSON not html (where I can put utf8 header)

Comment: What is your IDE? It could be because of your file encoding.
Are you sure you are saving your file as UTF-8 as well?